# Upload file to logged in user's google drive

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, google-drive-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I am working on a web api and web page. That I would like to use to upload file to the logged in user's google drive.

I am using .net core Identity for authentication and I have authenticated users and that part is working file.

So the identity middleware knows about the user.
Now I would like to send the file to the users drive.

I am getting:

```
Access to the path 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\config\\systemprofile' is denied.
```

As far as I understand that means he is trying to authenticate the user on the server. witch he can't

can I use the `singinManager` to get access to google drive api?

My `DriveService` code to initialize:

```
    string[] scopes = new string[] {
                     DriveService.Scope.Drive,
                     DriveService.Scope.DriveFile};

    GoogleConfiguration config = new AuthentificationConfiguration().GetGoogleSettings();
    var secrets = new ClientSecrets
    {
        ClientId = config.ClientId,
        ClientSecret = config.ClientSecret
    };            

    credential =  GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(secrets, scopes, user, CancellationToken.None).Result;
    _service = new DriveService(new Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer() {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential
    });
```

I know you can do that from the client directly but I would prefer not have client id and secret on the client.

So I would like to upload the file to my service and that forwards it to google

Is it possible?

Comment: Have you checked this same open issue in [github](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/933)?

Comment: Well I first wanted to know if I am on the right track. Since it is a first attempt at this